# Google transfer service error notification

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, error-logging, google-cloud-data-transfer

I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to find the answer. I set up a file transfer service between a S3 bucket and a google storage bucket. I know I can see the error messages by clicking on the file transfer, but I wan't to access the log, so I can set up an email notification when an error occurs. Where can I find the log? Or is there another way to set this email notification up?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Transfer Service does not currently have any mechanism for email/pubsub/etc. notifications about the progress of a job or errors it encounters.

Until such a feature exists, I think the closest available solution would be something based on the access logs or notifications directly from GCS or S3 (but that would include other traffic on the bucket, not just Transfer Service). E.g., for errors encountered when writing objects to GCS, you could analyze the [access logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) or the [object change notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications).